Upgrade chromedriver
ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 123 Current browser version is 125.0.6422.77
how I can fix this issue in selenium project using eclipse , can't run my project  i downloaded new version fromhttps://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ version 125.0.6422.78
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 123
Current browser version is 125.0.6422.77 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

I just had same issue. I solved it by downloading latest chrome driver from this site: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
Hope it helps!!
